# jQuery script is not working inside 'head' tag

Tags: jquery

so i wrote a simple script and enqueued it properly.

**my-jquery-script.js:**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('#some_id').on('click','.clone',function(e){
alert('clicked');
/*.....*/
e.preventDefault();
});
});
```

**functions.php:**

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_function' );

function my_function() {

wp_enqueue_script( 'my-jquery-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/my-jquery-script.js' );

}
```

**some-page.php:**

```
<?php wp_head(); ?>
<body>

<form>
<div id="some_id">
<a href="#" class="clone">button</a>
</div>
</form>

</body>
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
```

it's not working but when i include jQuery script manually into *some-page.php* like this:

```
<?php wp_head(); ?>
<body>

<form>
<div id="some_id">
<a href="#" class="clone">button</a>
</div>
<script type='text/javascript' src='<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . "/js/my-jquery-script.js"; ?>'></script>
</form>

</body>
<?php wp_footer(); ?>
```

it's working but "$(document).ready () fires twice" as mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10727002/jquery-document-ready-fires-twice

What am i doing wrong? Any help would be appreciated.

*update: I also noticed that `$(document.body).on('click','.clone',function(e){ }` selector is working instead of id selector.*

Answer (score 2):

If your script depends on jQuery, you have to declare that dependency to make sure WordPress will enqueue it earlier than yours.

```
wp_enqueue_script( 
    'my-jquery-script', 
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/my-jquery-script.js',
    [ 'jquery' ] /* declare the dependency */
);
```

Comment: tried `wp_enqueue_script( 'my-jquery-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/my-jquery-script.js', array('jquery') );` but no luck. I also noticed that `$(document.body).on('click','.clone',function(e){ }` selector is working instead of id selector. Sad thing that i need to select id's!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing theme and it resolved my problem.